# How to blit image without background in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

[image]

I want to blit only green triangle of this image on pygame surface.

My code:

```py
import pygame

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800))
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    win.fill((255,255,255))
    Image = pygame.image.load('sample.jpg').convert()
    Image.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
    win.blit(Image,(80,80))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

[image]

When I run that code it blit image like this.

How can I do this?

Comment: The green triangle image should have been saved as PNG rather than JPG. JPG is loss and produces artifacts like that.

Answer (score 2):

If you load your original triangle bitmap into a graphics editor like [The GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/), selecting the colours in the area around your triangle giving problems shows that these colours are not *exactly* black, but very very dark grey, e.g. `( 0, 0, 3 )`.  This is probably because the image is saved as a JPEG, where there is non-pixel-perfect image storage, and the colours have become corrupt.

Try this re-draw image, a .PNG - which does have pixel-perfect compression:

`sample.png`

[image: sample.tri]

But if you're going to the trouble, you may as well just make the unwanted sections transparent with an alpha channel, then PyGame will hide the background automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, pygame doesn't do a good job in color filtering. Instead you can try to blit a png image which has alpha transparency built in and you can use tools such as GIMP or photoshop to make the transparent image.
But if you have a lot of images and you want to do the process automatically you can use opencv to filter colors seamlessly; here is a good tutorial on this:

https://realpython.com/python-opencv-color-spaces/

After filtering the specified color, You can also use morphological operations to achieve a better result:
https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html